# list of il2cpp breaking features

Tags: unity, android, il2cpp

as you may know, il2cpp build does not work like mono build or playing just in the editor.

there are some c# features or libraries/plugins that make il2cpp doesn't work properly.

most of the time logger on Android or other platforms doesn't show the main reason.

is it possible to list the features that are highly probable that make problems for il2cpp builds?